# Is this really a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, this question was asked: [How to pass arguments to add_action()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/109985/32110)

After I answered it, the question was marked as a duplicate to this one: [Passing a parameter to filter and action functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/45901/32110)

Looking at just the titles, these appear to be the same question.  (The simple answer to that question is "You can't pass a parameter via the add_action function.")  However, the situations that the OPs were in are totally different.  In yesterday's question, the OP was calling `add_action` from inside an object class, and was confused about passing the parameter to the callback function, also inside the object class.  In addition, he was using `wp_schedule_single_event`, not `do_action`, to perform the action.  He got an answer that worked for him and did not have anything to do with the "duplicate" question.

Are these really duplicate questions?  Does the question need to be edited to make it look less like a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

**The questions are duplicate.**

The *answers* are completely different.

That is my opinion at least.

Comment: If the title of yesterday's question got changed to "Calling add_action inside an object class", would that make the question no longer a duplicate?

Comment: Probably. Such is the way of judgement. And perception. And speculation. And all three things are at play here. And none of them are constant.

Comment: So, if the **Titles** are duplicate, but the **actual questions** are distinct, wouldn't the correct course of action be to **modify the title**, rather than to close a non-duplicate question as duplicate?